# Where does the phrase "It's a good job that ..." come from?

Tags: etymology, phrases, word-usage

In [a recent link](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59802/17956) the phrase "*It's a good job that..."* is used.
I take it to mean the same as *It's a good thing that ...*  but I've never in my almost 50 years of English heard *job* used like that before.  Word-wise it makes no sense to me that it even came into being.

In what part of the world is that expression used, and how did it get started?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED’s definition 5 of *job* is ‘A state of affairs, a situation, a set of circumstances. Frequently with modifying adjective, as bad, good, etc.’ The earliest citation supporting this definition is from 1690:

> 'Twas an ill jobb for one Misfortune so soon to fall upon the neck of one another.

The first citation of *good job* is from Gilbert and Sullivan’s ‘Trial by Jury’ of 1876, which helpfully illustrates both that sense and the sense of ‘a piece of work’:

> ‘So we've finished with the job, And a good job too!’

The origin of *job* itself is uncertain, but it is possibly related to the word *job* meaning 'a cartload; the amount that a horse and cart can bring at one time.'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your second example makes sense to me since the *piece of work* definition is familiar to me.  The 'set of circumstances' definition is not used in the U.S. as far as I know- where is it in common use?  In that area would the statement, "It's a good job the sun is bright today" be a reasonable thing to say?  No one has really *done* anything to cause that situation; so I would typically say instead, "It's a good *thing* the sun is..." or even just "It's good that the sun is..."

Comment: @Jim: 'It's a good job the sun is bright today' (or variations on it) would be quite normal in British English, but 'a good thing' would also be found.

Comment: The G&S line is actually a multi-way pun.  An earlier line in the same verse says "it was managed by a job" which, in the 19th century, implied, if not actually meant, that there was corruption of some sort in the judge's appointment. This has the chorus "And a Good Job Too" implying that the corruption was a good thing and/or that the conduct of the corruption  was well conducted. The final line and chorus say "So we've finished with the job. And a good job too" where "job" refers to the end of the case, the corruption, and the fact that getting to the end was a good thing.